# How to pass the image as a structure parameter to C function of libfprint using JNI

Tags: java, c, pointers, java-native-interface, bufferedimage

I am working with a biometric finger print scanning device, and I have already developed a Java application to get the finger print image data. Now I want to process that image and do the fingerprint matching. For that I have found one open source library, [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/).

This library provides some functions to process the image and also functions for matching those images. As the application is written in Java the image is passed from Java code through [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to the C code. Now for example the function for image binarization in the library is as shown below

```
struct fp_img *fp_img_binarize(struct fp_img *img)
```

What should I pass from the Java code to such functions in the C code which takes the structure data as a parameter? Or how do I pass the values from the Java code to the C functions if they take a structure as a parameter? Or how do I write the JNI layer in this case?

Comment: Can you pass the struct address as a unsigned long value to the C function?

Comment: Thank you for your replay.I don't know how to pass it,can you please explain this in brief how to pass the unsigned long value to C function ?

Comment: ..Once I use OpenCV . The java lib give a function to get the address of class Mat . :).Sorry no useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write a JNI function that will take your image from Java and converts it to a fp_img structure for libfprint (you can't just call any C-library function from Java).

The structure in libfprint looks like this

```
struct fp_img {
    int width;
    int height;
    size_t length;
    uint16_t flags;
    struct fp_minutiae *minutiae;
    unsigned char *binarized;
    unsigned char data[0];
};
```

libfprint is not really meant to be used with external images. Normally the fingerprint images should be acquired using libfprint in the first place.

But you can create a new image by calling the function

```
struct fp_img *fpi_img_new(size_t length)
```

with length=width*height. The problem is, that this function might not be declared in the libfprint headers so you will have to declare it yourself or just reimplement it. It is simply doing this:

```
struct fp_img *img = malloc(sizeof(struct fp_img) + length);
img->length = length;
```

You should then probably also set

```
img->width = width;
img->height = height;
```

You can then access the raw image data (8-bit greyscale) with this function (I assume rows-column order, i.e. data[x + y*img->width] would be the (x,y) pixel).

```
unsigned char *fp_img_get_data(struct fp_img *img)
```

You can treat this array as being of size=length. You can then simply write the pixels of your Java image into this array within your JNI function.
When you finally have your image you can pass it to the fp_img_binarize function.

Comment: Hey I am using http://code.google.com/p/jlibfprint/ Jlibfprint to wrap libfprint. There is a ReadMEFile in the Jlibfprint_jni which have a line: specify the JDK path of the source files of the libfprint you have just patched. I am not able to set this path. What path I have to set. Is it img.c path? Could you help me please?